# Is it possible to sent default params to all http request in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

Is there any way  to sent default params to all http request in rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can use rails [**`default_url_options`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options). *You can **set default options that all url_for-based methods will use**. You can specify default options in the form of a hash*

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { params_name: "params_value" }
end
```

Comment: default_url_options are deprecated in rails3.

Comment: @kannathasan check `These similar methods exist in v4.0.2:` in link

Comment: @kannathasan checkout it's implementation to set locale in params http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Answer (score 0):

You can [define defaults](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) in your `routes.rb`:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope defaults: {foo: 'bar'} do

    # requests to routes defined here will have params[:foo] set to 'bar'

  end

end
```